# 400 Bad Request & Update for Getting Token for Microsoft Translator API Azure

Tags: azure, datetime, groovy, libreoffice, microsoft-translator

I have an old system that has been using the Microsoft Translator API before we were asked to get a subscription with Azure.

One thing that was being translated was the date on a certificate that was being generated from a LibreOffice template using a function in groovy and jooscript in the template itself.

The date was being translated from English to Chinese and was constructed using SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").

Since the change/update, we have been getting this error:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=06+December+2017&from=en&to=zh-CHT

The request being sent to the API: Translate?text=06+December+2017&from=en&to=zh-CHT

Found that when we change the text to anything it gives the same response, i.e. translating "Hello" would give the same error.

Expected response: 六　日　十二　月　二零一七年,i.e. 6 day, 12 month,2017 year. although the format is changed using SimpleDateFormat to dd MMM yyyy.

This is the groovy function being called in the LibreOffice template using jooscript field script:

```
public String translate(String text, String from, String to){
def client = new 
RESTClient("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate")
client.get(path:'', query:[text:"$text", from:"$from", to:"$to"], headers:
["Authorization":"Bearer ${getToken()}"]).xml
}
```

Does anyone know why this error is now occurring?

I want to know how do I update the below code (if it needs to be updated) to work with the new Microsoft Translator API Azure store so I can include the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key, https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken and such. Do I still need the ID and secret?

Please note that I didn't write the original code, and the company seems to have lost access to the old account that provided the credentials for the translation and such.

```
def id = *********
def secret = *********
def getToken = {
def client = new 
RESTClient("https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13")

try{
    client.post(){
        type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        urlenc client_id:id , client_secret:secret , scope: "http://api.microsofttranslator.com", grant_type: "client_credentials"
    }.json.access_token
}
catch(e){ 
   e.printStackTrace(); return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm not adding it as an answer because it's a wild guess(I don't use translator): I found a C# sample that has the url parameters in lower case. I've seen other azure services throw 400s when they were being case sensitive about URLs and their parameters. It's been a long time since I've seen that happen, but it may be worth looking into if someone else doesn't get an answer for you. https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/TranslateWithAzureSubscriptionKeyAuthentication/blob/master/Program.cs

Comment: @JimL Thanks, I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft DataMarket retired April 2017so the client-secret and client-Id will no longer work. The Microsoft Translator API has moved to the Microsoft Azure portal. You will need to:

- create an Azure account and
- subscribe to Azure and subsequently
- subscribe to the Translator API and
- make minor code changes to the oAuth token.

You can find detailed instructions on the above steps at: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-microsoft-translator-moves-to-the-azure-portal

Please let us know if you have any further questions.

Kindly,
Gwenda
Microsoft Translator Team